# Complicated node shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes

I am trying to make a diagram of a mobile network. For this purpose I have created a base station/cell tower drawing in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75} {
    \draw[thick] (\x,0) -- (\x,0.5);
}

\draw[thick] (-0.75,0) -- (0.75,0);

\path[name path=left, draw, thick] (-0.75, -3) -- (-0.0625, 0);
\path[name path=right, draw, thick] (0.75, -3) -- (0.0625, 0);

\path[name path=int1] (-1, -0.625) -- (1, -0.625);
\path[name path=int2] (-1, -1.5) -- (1, -1.5);
\path[name path=int3] (-1, -2.5) -- (1, -2.5);

\path[name intersections={of=int1 and left,by=li1}];
\path[name intersections={of=int2 and left,by=li2}];
\path[name intersections={of=int3 and left,by=li3}];

\path[name intersections={of=int1 and right,by=ri1}];
\path[name intersections={of=int2 and right,by=ri2}];
\path[name intersections={of=int3 and right,by=ri3}];

\draw (li1) -- (ri1);
\draw (li2) -- (ri2);
\draw (li3) -- (ri3);
\draw (li1) -- (ri2);
\draw (li2) -- (ri1);
\draw (li2) -- (ri3);
\draw (li3) -- (ri2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to use a tikz picture as a shape for a node so I can place it easily in a bigger diagram?

Comment: You can nest a `tikzpicture` inside a node in another `tikzpicture` using `\node {\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}};`

Comment: @vipa I wouldn't generally recommend that. While it can work, it can also cause unexpected problems due to inheritance of options. It's also usually unnecessary. Searching for *nesting tikzpictures* here on the site will lead to several questions about this.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I must admit that is not an elegant solution. The Schr.'s cat solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Yes, of course you can make this a pic. You do not need intersections for this either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/power pole/.style={code={
 \draw[thick] \foreach \X in {0.25, 0.75} {(-\X,0.5) |- (\X,0) -- (\X,0.5)}
    (-0.75, -3) -- (-0.0625, 0) coordinate[pos=0.175] (l3)
        coordinate[pos=0.5] (l2) coordinate[pos=0.775] (l1)
    (0.75, -3) -- (0.0625, 0) coordinate[pos=0.175] (r3)
        coordinate[pos=0.5] (r2) coordinate[pos=0.775] (r1);
  \draw (l1) -- (r1) (l2) -- (r2) (l3) -- (r3)
  (l1) -- (r2) (l2) -- (r3) (l3) -- (r2) (l2) -- (r1);
}}]

\path  pic{power pole};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution, as a beginner I sometimes can't see the forest for the trees!